# a right query that take all records that contains time_start<=time_pc<=time_finish

Tags: mysql, time

I am from Indonesia.. I have a table in database which it's name tb_schedule that contains 3 fields: id_schedule, time_start(time), time_finish(time).
Ex: 10, 08:00:00, 09:45:00 ..etc

In my php, i have time variable that taken from pc's time.
Ex: $timeNow='08:10:00'; My problem is I can't find a right query that take all records that contains time_start<=time_pc<=time_finish. Ex: 08:00:00<=$timeNow<=09:45:00 
Please help me.. 
Thank you before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_Schedule WHERE time_start <= '08:10:00' AND
                                time_finish >= '08:10:00';
```

Where `'08:10:00'` is the value of your `$timeNow` variable.

Here's an SQL Fiddle so that you can play with the queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/187a0/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE $timeNow BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:45:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please state what is time_pc and define $timeNow properly. Also, tell me what query statements you have considered and I will see what i can do